# Calling instance of adapter class plugged into port is causing mypy issues

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, hexagonal-architecture

I'm currently plugging an Adapter into a port in a handler which can help you get an instance of that port. Here is a simple setup to reproduce:

```py
from typing import Protocol


class SomePort(Protocol):
    def caller(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class SomeAdapter:
    def caller(self):
        print("Called")


class SomeController:
    @staticmethod
    def get_instance(port: SomePort) -> SomePort:
        return port()


instance = SomeController.get_instance(port=SomeAdapter)
instance.caller()
```

This is working just fine in code but in `mypy` I'm getting the following issues:

```bash
$ mypy --version
mypy 0.931

$ mypy test/test.py 
test/test.py:17: error: "SomePort" not callable
test/test.py:20: error: Argument "port" to "get_instance" of "SomeController" has incompatible type "Type[SomeAdapter]"; expected "SomePort"
```

anything I've misunderstood here? Running the script prints `Called` just fine, but mypy is unhappy about the way I've set this up. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Related to subclass in typehinting question, but here is what fixed my issue: `Type[SomePort]` is used for a callable, uninstanciated class. `SomePort` is used when it is an instance of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `port` parameter in `SomeController.get_instance` to accept a *class* that is a subtype of `SomePort`, you need to annotate it with `type[SomePort]` instead of `SomePort`.

The latter (as you have it in your example) would express that `port` should be an *instance* of the type `SomePort`. Since `SomePort` is not callable (no `__call__` method defined), you get that first Mypy error. And because `SomeAdapter` is a *class* that follows the `SomePort` protocol rather than an instance of such a class, you get that second error.

If you are on Python `<3.9` use [`typing.Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) instead of the built-in `type`, i.e. `typing.Type[SomePort]`.

Comment: so when it's an instance of `SomePort` you annotate it as `SomePort`, but when it's the uninstantiated class it's `Type[SomePort]`?

Comment: @SteinnHauserMagnusson Correct. See the documentation for [`typing.Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) I linked in my answer.

Comment: The problem is also that a Protocol class cannot be instatiated.

Comment: @hussic No, that has nothing to do with this. Nowhere did OP attempt to instantiate a `Protocol` class directly.

Comment: Yes, you are right.